# Windows Phone 8.1 app - how to get it to my phone?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I just created my first windows phone app. I do not intend to put it in the wp store, it was just an exercise for me. Now I want to use it and test it on my windows phone but I cannot find a way to do that.

Microsoft wants me to register as a developer and pay them money (I feel like they're kidding me). All I want to do is get the app on a phone, MY phone.

does anyone know how to do that? I'm getting desperate, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_device) seems pretty clear on what you need to do.

Comment: unfortunately that's not what I want to do. I do not wish to sign up as a developer

Comment: Either 8 or 8.1 Or now Metro app You can do it

Answer (score 2):

Any developer can unlock their phone to install up to two apps on their device using the Windows Phone Developer Registration Tool to register your device, you do not have to pay for a Dev Centre account unless you want to deploy up to 10 apps on a device or publish to the store which you don't want to do. All you'll need is a Microsoft Account and don't need to register as a developer, can refer to the [How to register your phone for development for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UsingtheWindowsPhoneDeveloperRegistrationTool) documentation for details

Comment: but how do I do it ? My phone is unlocked but ... what then? I copied the appx file to my windows phone but that didn't help because I cannot install it, so how do I do it?

Comment: You should be able to connect the phone then use the Deploy option in Visual Studio, I think there's a separate deployment tool but if run app or debug it should be available to run in list of apps once this has been done on the device, but can check this once have access to tools later today

Comment: I don't have the "device" option in visual studio for the windows 8.1. app

Comment: The Deploy option should be under Build there will be a Deploy <app name> option could try this or choosing Device from the Debug dropdown - either of these should deploy the app to the device if it's been unlocked, connected and available to Visual Studio to target

Answer (score 1):

**You need to have only an Microsoft account( no any paid developer)** , using this you can register the phone you want to test on.

You can now register one phone without a developer account, as you can see in the prerequisites of registering a phone:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

**Registering your phone:**

- To install the app you need to unlock the device first, for this you
  need to connect your Windows Phone via USB to system and start the
  Registration tool. The tool detects the phone and asks you to login
  into your Microsoft account(live/outlook)
- after this step the phone is successfully unlocked.
- After unlocking the phone you can use visual studio or Windows Phone
  Power Tools or Application Deployment tool to install applications on
  the device.
- Previously we need to have a developer account for installation of
  apps on devices but now a Microsoft Account(live/outlook) is enough
  for doing so.

To register a phone, use the Windows Phone Developer Registration tool follow the link:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UsingtheWindowsPhoneDeveloperRegistrationTool

Comment: my phone is already registered, what I don't know is what to do next. I have an appx and I have a registered windows phone. What's next?

Comment: 1. In Visual Studio, open a Windows Phone project.
2. On the Standard toolbar, select a target.
3. To deploy your app to a connected device, select the Device option.

Comment: To deploy and run your app with debugging, on the Debug menu, click Start Debugging, or press F5.
To deploy and run your app without debugging, on the Debug menu, click Start without Debugging, or press Ctrl+F5.
Your app is deployed and started.
To deploy your app without running it, on the Build menu, click Deploy Solution.

Comment: Still yo are not Getting just follow the link:  https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7XDqUG9vUmAC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=how+to+deploy+app+in+visual+studio+to+connected+phone&source=bl&ots=Rv1Cs1UNga&sig=TmM3LQDKXhkNyZP0I9brzMPaBCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4uKP3zrDJAhVDv44KHbgZDyEQ6AEITjAJ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20deploy%20app%20in%20visual%20studio%20to%20connected%20phone&f=false

Comment: I never had the "device" option in visual studio so that's where my mistake was. Thank you for describing the steps, that's how I was finally able to figure out what to do.

Comment: You welcome:).Make sure your project is set as the "Startup Project",  otherwise: Rght click on the project and select "Set as start up project"